# Actor isolation and non-sendable closure (use higher-order function inside Actor)

Tags: swift, swift-concurrency

How to adjust `forEachAsync` for use within `TestActor` without a warning? It should stay reusable in other places.

I need `TestActor` to pass around non-sendable stuff within it. And I want to use higher-order convenience functions like `forEachAsync` within it. Execution is sequential on purpose.

Build settings -> Strict Concurrency Checking: Complete

```swift
class NotSendable { }

actor TestActor {
    func foo() async {
        // No problem
        for _ in 1...3 {
            await bar(NotSendable())
        }
        
        // Warning: Passing argument of non-sendable type '(Int) async -> ()'
        // outside of actor-isolated context may introduce data races
        await (1...3).forEachAsync { _ in
            await bar(NotSendable())
        }
    }
    
    func bar(_: NotSendable) async { }
}

extension Sequence {
    func forEachAsync(_ operation: (Element) async -> Void) async {
        for element in self {
            await operation(element)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @loremipsum I believe there's a mismatch between the question here and what you're answering. In the code above, the operation **should** occur within the Actor's context. This code isn't intending to switch contexts in an unsafe way. And in fact, I believe at runtime it will be in the right context. But the compiler doesn't seem able to determine that, and I'm not immediately certain how to express it (or if it is expressible in current Swift). This is an excellent question (even if I do not like this extension :D).

Answer (score 3):

#### Update

[SE-0420 – Inheritance of actor isolation](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/main/proposals/0420-inheritance-of-actor-isolation.md) has been accepted and implemented in Swift 6. I think it will work like this:

```swift
extension Sequence {
    func forEachAsync(
        isolation: isolated (any Actor)? = #isolation,
        _ operation: (Element) async -> Void
    ) async {
        for element in self {
            await operation(element)
        }
    }
}
```

#### Original Answer

I found this solution:

```swift
actor TestActor {
    func foo() async {
        await (1...3).forEachAsync(self) { _ in
            await bar(NotSendable())
        }
    }
    
    func bar(_: NotSendable) async { }
}

extension Sequence {
    func forEachAsync(
        _: isolated Actor,
        _ operation: (Element) async -> Void
    ) async where Element: Sendable {
        for element in self {
            await operation(element)
        }
    }
}
```

This gets rid of the warning. I'm not sure if it's actually safe. Unfortunately, the `Element: Sendable` requirement limits its usefulness.

Here's a better challenge that it doesn't pass:

```swift
func foo() async {
    let nonSendables = [NotSendable(), NotSendable()]

    // No problem
    for notSendable in nonSendables {
        await bar(notSendable)
    }

    // Warning: Type 'NotSendable' does not conform to the 'Sendable' protocol
    await nonSendables.forEachAsync(self) { notSendable in
        await bar(notSendable)
    }
}
```

By the way, I found this directly related Swift evolution proposal:
[SE-0420 – Inheritance of actor isolation](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/main/proposals/0420-inheritance-of-actor-isolation.md)

Comment: Fascinating (+1). FWIW, I tried the [toolchain associated with SE-0420](https://forums.swift.org/t/se-0420-inheritance-of-actor-isolation/69638) and it compiles your code without warnings. So you might have to wait for the proposal to be accepted and integrated into future Swift version. (As an aside, part of me hopes that they reconsider the implementation currently embodied by proposal; it is completely unintuitive to change the async context of a *function* based upon, not a qualifier on the function, but rather an `isolated` *property* that you never actually explicitly use.)

Comment: I’d personally prefer them to pursue one of the “[Future Directions](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/main/proposals/0338-clarify-execution-non-actor-async.md#future-directions)” contemplated in SE-0338.

Comment: Yes it's strange. Do you think the already accepted [SE-0417](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/main/proposals/0417-task-executor-preference.md) can solve this via `await withTaskExecutorPreference(self.unownedExecutor) { ... }`?

Comment: I'd suggest you just try out the [toolchain](https://forums.swift.org/t/se-0417-task-executor-preference/68958) and see…

Comment: You might also read [0313-actor-isolation-control](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/main/proposals/0313-actor-isolation-control.md), specifically section "Actor-isolated parameters".

Answer (score 2):

As of Swift 5.7, `async` functions not isolated to any actor will “formally run on a generic executor associated with no actor.” The rationale for this is outlined in [SE-0338 – Clarify the Execution of Non-Actor-Isolated Async Functions](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/main/proposals/0338-clarify-execution-non-actor-async.md).

So, in this case, the non-isolated `async` function, `forEachAsync`, will not run on `TestActor`, but rather on a generic executor, thus introducing a switch in concurrency context. The aforementioned Swift Evolution proposal acknowledges that the old behavior (of staying on the current actor, if any) was effective in “minimizing switches between executors”, but they concluded it was worth this cost for the reasons outlined in SE-0338.

Technically, you can achieve what you want with global actors, but it is ugly and largely defeats the purpose of the simple `extension`. You might be able to write a [macro](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/applying-macros/) that does this expansion for you, but it is likely not worth it.

I know this is not the answer you are looking for, but the simplest solution is to just stick with the `for`-`in` loop. Or, if practical, revisit whether you might just make the object `Sendable` (and add the missing `@Sendable` qualifier to the closure parameter of that function).

Comment: That's very unfortunate. `forEachAsync` is just a simplified example, the actual functions are way more useful. And since I am dealing with SwiftData / Core Data I cannot make the object sendable. Passing its ID or an equivalent sendable struct around is cumbersome and defeats the purpose of the actor.

Comment: I might suggest posting a question re that, specifically. I haven’t played around with it, but it strikes me that a `ModelActor` is a promising avenue. Or, if your `ModelContainer` is isolated to the main actor, just isolate your extension’s method to `@MainActor`, too. I was answering the “general-purpose non-isolated asynchronous” question, which is antithetical to isolating to a particular actor. But if your function is working on SwiftData/CoreData isolated to a particular actor, then maybe isolating the extension‘s function to that actor might be viable (and avoid context switches).

Comment: I am using ModelActor and have also tried isolating everything to a global actor using annotations. Unfortunately, the warning remained. I might post a separate question specifically on SwiftData but I'm not sure the problem is much different from this.

Comment: Interesting. When I isolated everything (e.g., both the function and the function’s closure parameter) to the same global actor, the warnings went away.

Comment: You're right, when the extension is isolated to the global actor as well, the warning disappears. But as you said that largely defeats the purpose of the extension because it makes it less reusable.